# I'm using react-router-dom v6. To adjust the scroll position after page is moved, I used ScrollRestoration. I'm curious about where to use this

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

What I'm curious about is not how to use the code, but the criteria for where to put it to work.

I have three main components to build my project.

index.tsx

```
import App from "App";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
  // <React.StrictMode>
  <App />
  // </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js

```
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Root from "./Root";
import Home from "./pages/Home/Home";
import { Location } from "./pages/Location/components/Location";
import { Recruit } from "./pages/Recruit/components/Recruit";
import { Service } from "./pages/Service/components/Service";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: "Not Found",
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: "/service",
        element: <Service />,
      },
      {
        path: "/recruit",
        element: <Recruit />,
      },
      {
        path: "/location",
        element: <Location />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```

Root.tsx

```
import { Footer } from "Layout/Footer";
import { Header } from "Layout/Header";
import { Outlet, ScrollRestoration } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Root() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header></Header>
      <ScrollRestoration />
      <Outlet></Outlet>
      <Footer></Footer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

To re-adjust the scroll to the top, I used `<ScrollRestoration />` from the library in the index.tsx file because in most posts and articles on the Internet, they use it in the index.tsx file.

However, in my project, it didn't work. My web screen came out black without nothing.

So, I used `<ScrollRestoration />` in the App.js file, but it also didn't work even though I change the extension of the file from js to ts or tsx.

Lastly, I used `<ScrollRestoration />` in the Root.tsx with `<Outlet>`. It works well.

So, I solved my problem, but I couldn't understand why?

Is there a standard for the location or file that uses it? If so, what is the standard?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a standard for the location or file that uses it? If so, what
> is the standard?

Yes, it is recommended to render in the root route of your router.

Straight from the [ScrollRestoration](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/scroll-restoration) docs:

> > ⚠️ **IMPORTANT**
> >
> > This feature ***only works if using a data router***, see [Picking a Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router)
>
> You should only render one of these and it's recommended you ***render it
> in the root route*** of your app:
>
> ```
> import { ScrollRestoration } from "react-router-dom";
>
> function RootRouteComponent() {
>   return (
>     <div>
>       {/* ... */}
>       <ScrollRestoration />
>     </div>
>   );
> }
> ```

The `ScrollRestoration` didn't work in your `index.tsx` or `App` component because you rendered it outside the data router, i.e. outside `RouterProvider`.

It worked when you moved it into your root `Root` layout route component *inside* the `RouterProvider`.

Comment: @Jay Welcome, glad to help. Did this answer/address your question/issue?